# Complete square to show that $(x-2y)^4+64xy+16 \geq 0$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, factoring, square-numbers

I want to prove that

> $f(x,y) = (x-2y)^4+64xy+16 \geq 0$

Using only algebraic methods (I guess it can be solved via **completing the square**).

I didn't manage to do so. Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write $t = x-2y$ so $x=t+2y$ and now we have $$\begin{align} f(t,y) &= t^4+64y(t+2y)+16 \\ &= 128y^2+64yt +(t^4+16) \end{align}$$ This is quadratic function on $y$. It discriminant is $$\begin{align}  D&= 64^2t^2  -4\cdot 128 (t^4 +16)\\ & = -128\cdot 4 (t^4-8t^2+16)\\ &= -128\cdot 4(t^2-4)^2\\ &\leq 0\end{align}  $$

and we are done.

Comment: Can you please elaborate why this means that $f(x,y) \geq 0$ for any $x,y$?

Comment: If quadratic function has nonpositive discriminant, then it has at most one zero. So it graph is completly under $x$-axis or it touch it, since leadin coefficent is positive.

Answer (score 4):

You can complete the square.

$f(x,y) = (x-2y)^4+64xy+16$

Note that $4xy = x^2 + 4y^2 - (x-2y)^2 $

So $f(x,y) = (x-2y)^4 + 8 [x^2 + 4y^2 - (x-2y)^2] + 32xy + 16$

$ = (x-2y)^4 - 8 (x-2y)^2 + 16 + 8(x^2+4y^2 + 4xy)$

$ = [(x-2y)^2 - 4]^2 + 8 (x+2y)^2 \geq 0$

Comment: +1)This is the answer I'm looking for .:)

Comment: @lonestudent thank you :)

Comment: Great! Thank you. That's elegant. Can you please give some method or intuition of how to find this out?

Comment: you are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can use also AM-GM inequality $a+b\geq 2\sqrt{ab}$: $$(x-2y)^4+ 16 \geq 8\cdot (x-2y)^2$$

then $$\begin{align} f(x,y) &\geq 8\cdot (x-2y)^2 +64 xy \\ &= 8\cdot (x^2-4xy + 4y^2 +8xy) \\& =8(x^2+4xy +4y^2) \\
& =8(x+2y)^2 \\
&\geq 0
\end{align} 
$$

Comment: Why is $f(x,y) \geq 8\cdot (x-2y)^2 +16 xy$? Where did $64xy$ go? we don't know that $x,y \geq 0$

Comment: My mistake, it is 64 not 16.